# Node.JS EBADF error on npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've been trying to get started learning React on my Mac. When I try to run `npx create-react-app my-app` it gives the following error:

> `npm ERR! code EBADF npm ERR! syscall connect npm ERR! errno EBADF npm
> ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed,
> reason: connect EBADF 104.16.18.35:443
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/Jeremy/.npm/_logs/2022-08-09T06_30_08_356Z-debug-0.log`

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node - making sure it was up-todate, etc, but no luck! I'm pretty stuck as a complete beginner just trying to follow a few tutorials. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I've googled code EBADF, it seems not many people have this issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that I was using a VPN that restricted the web traffic to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app. Once I disable the VPN, everything worked as expected.